# Elegant/pythonic way of calling a hundred different functions in python?

Tags: python

I have a hundred unique functions, let's call them `func_{i}()` where `{i}` is the number of the function, for example `func_56()`. I have a loop where I essentially need to do:

```
for item in list:
    values[0] = func_0(item,values[0]) 
    values[1] = func_1(item,values[1])
    ...
    values[99] = func_99(item,values[99])
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this? I can think of:

```
for item in list:
    for i in range(100):
        values[i] = eval('func_' + str(i) + '(item, values[i]')
```

But `eval()` is generally not considered good practice.

Alternatively:

```
function_list = [func_0, func_1 .... ] # is there a way of doing this programmatically?
for item in list:
    for i in range(100):
        values[i] = function_list[i](item, values[i])
```

But constructing the function list still seems ugly by hand and `eval()` seems like the only way to do that. Even then, this snippet seems like it could be made more elegant and pythonic and this is probably not the most efficient way of doing things.

For the purpose of this question, it's safe to assume that each `func_{i}()` is entirely unique and there is no way to have them share code and no way to condense it down to less than 100 unique functions.

Comment: Are the functions scoped somewhere?

Comment: Where did all those functions come from in the first place? Can you *generate* these? Are they all listed in a module?

Comment: They're functions that I've written separately, within scope, but what they are isn't really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the functions are all scoped in an object, like `all_func`, you could use `getattr(..)` to obtain the function:

```
for items in list:
    for i in range(100):
        values[i] = getattr(all_func,'func_%s'%i)(item,values[i])
```

This will be safer since:

1. You have control about which elements are in `all_func`; and
2. You perform a single call with the feeded elements, so a hacker that would somehow want to inject arbitrary code would have a harder job.

Nevertheless it is rather inelegant to define hundreds of functions to begin with. This usually means there is a parameter such that `func_42(para,meter)` could be generalized to `func(42,para,meter)`, etc. You should consider redesigning your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the most elegant it can get. Unfortunately I can't really generalize the functions, but putting them all in an object and then calling them like this does make sense. It's similar to the eval() solution but doesn't actually call eval().

Comment: @HalT: well it give you more control and thus will be safer than `eval` but mind that it is still not a "nice" way. Furthermore it can be problematic: if you for instance decide to rename `fuc_{i}` to `foo_{i}`, the IDE will probably not refactor this properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
for item in list:
    for i in range(100):
        values[i] = locals()["func_%d" % (i)](item, values[i])
```

Depending on how your functions are defined, you can use `locals()` or `globals()` or `getattr(some_module, "func_%d" % (i))`.